# clang-3.8 and compiler-rt vs libgcc

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have been using `clang-3.5` to happily build bitcode versions of musl libc and
use the result to produce nice stand alone executables.

Recent attempts with `clang-3.8` have not been so happy. It seems that 
the bitcode `clang-3.8` generates uses functions defined in

```
compiler-rt/lib/builtins
```

Typical examples of functions I find polluting the bitcode are `mulxc3`, `mulsc3`, and `muldc3`. I can solve this by linking against `libgcc`, or even the llvm alternative if I had any clear idea of what that was. Though  I would rather prevent the problem from happening in the first place.

I have seen mention of flags like `rtlib=compiler-rt` etc, but have found precious little documentation on the subject.

So here are some simple questions.

1. Is it possible to prevent `clang` from using the `compiler-rt/lib/builtins`
   in the emitted bitcode? Or if not
2. Does llvm produce a version of libgcc that I could use. Actually I would
   probably build a bitcode version of it, but that is besides the point.

Love to hear some guidance on this.

**Added 12/8/2016:** So I will illustrate my issues with a particular workflow that
people can reproduce if they wish, or, more likely, just point out where I am being stupid.

So start by checking out:

[musllv](https://github.com/SRI-CSL/musllvm.git)

and follow the instructions in the README.to compile (here I am using clang-3.8 on ubuntu 14.04)

```
WLLVM_CONFIGURE_ONLY=1  CC=wllvm ./configure --target=LLVM --build=LLVM 
make
cd lib
extract-bc -b libc.a
```

you will also need the bitcode of a simple executable. I will use nweb.c here.

```
 wllvm nweb.c -o nweb
 extract-bc nweb
```

Now we can do things like:

```
clang -static -nostdlib nweb.bc libc.a.bc crt1.o libc.a -o nweb
```

This workflow goes smoothly for clang-3.5 but for clang-3.8 we get:

```
clang -static -nostdlib nweb.bc libc.a.bc crt1.o libc.a -o nweb
/tmp/libc-f734a3.o: In function `cpowl':
libc.a.bc:(.text+0xbb9a): undefined reference to `__mulxc3'
/tmp/libc-f734a3.o: In function `cpowf':
libc.a.bc:(.text+0x38f7d): undefined reference to `__mulsc3'
/tmp/libc-f734a3.o: In function `csqrt':
libc.a.bc:(.text+0x78fc3): undefined reference to `__muldc3'
/tmp/libc-f734a3.o: In function `cpow':
libc.a.bc:(.text+0xafafc): undefined reference to `__muldc3'
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to seeinvocation)
```

So as @paul-brannan points out we could try

```
clang -static -nostdlib --rtlib=compiler-rt nweb.bc libc.a.bc crt1.o libc.a -o nweb
```

But this is where I am probably being stupid, because I get:

```
clang-3.8: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--rtlib=compiler-rt'
```

irregardless of whether I use it as a linking or compiling flag.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I believe this bug report is relevant: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16404

BTW, linking using --rtlib=compiler-rt solved my linking problems looking for __muloti4, while linking with libgcc did not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @paul-brannan, looks 'can-o-wormish'. Still I do not seem to have the midas touch. I'll post a follow up so that people can duplicate my issue, and nurse me to the promised land.

Comment: I'm adding this here, because while it doesn't answer my question it also seems relevant. [Build GNU-free executables with clang](https://blogs.gentoo.org/gsoc2016-native-clang/2016/05/31/build-gnu-free-executables-with-clang/)

Answer (score 0):

OK so I finally managed to make headway on this.  I built `llvm-3.8.1` together with the `compiler-rt` project using `wllvm` and `wllvm++`.

One of the build products was `libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.a`,
and from this archive I was able to extract the bitcode module

`libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.bc`

using the command:
`extract-bc -b libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.a`

This bitcode module has definitions for those pesky instrinsics like
`__mulxc3`, `__mulsc3`, and `__muldc3`.

Hallelujah!